# Can "require();" return global functions/variables?

Tags: node.js, require

Is there a way to put the exported functions of modules in the global namespace, rather than a module-specific one?

*Module*:

```
function sayName(name) {
    console.log("My name is " + name);
}
function sayAge(age) {
    console.log("My age is " + age);
}
module.exports = {sayName: sayName, sayAge: sayAge};
```

*Main file*:

```
const mod = require("./mod");
mod.sayName("Pedro"); // My name is Pedro
mod.sayAge(28); // My age is 28
```

This works fine, but I want to avoid having to refer to the module:

```
const mod = require("./mod");
sayName("Pedro"); // My name is Pedro
sayAge(28); // My age is 28
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

`require()` does not automatically add things to the global namespace like you're asking.  It just doesn't do that and is not how it works.  It returns a value which can be an individual value or an object or array full of multiple values.  You HAVE to assign the return value or some property on the return value to something in order to save it for later use.

You can use ES6 syntax to automatically create variables in the local scope for specific properties on the returned object from `require()` like this:

```
const {sayName, sayAge} = require('./mod');

sayName("Pedro"); // My name is Pedro
sayAge(28); // My age is 28
```

Keep in mind that these are not globals either.  They are module-level variables.  This is really just a language shortcut for this:

```
const temp = require('./mod');
const sayName = temp.sayName;
const sayAge = temp.sayAge;

sayName("Pedro"); // My name is Pedro
sayAge(28); // My age is 28
```

That language shortcut is useful for sure, but I wanted you to know what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
const {sayName, sayAge} = require('./mod');
```

and then refer to them without prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!!, you can add them to the **Global** object. (*This is considered as a bad practice as anyone can make changes to our functions*)

```
function sayName(name) {
    console.log("My name is " + name);
}
function sayAge(age) {
    console.log("My age is " + age);
}

global.sayName = sayName;
global.sayAge = sayAge;
```

So you can just call them directly without assigning to any local variables:

```
require("./mod");

sayName("Pedro"); // My name is Pedro
sayAge(28); // My age is 28
```